# Custom View for NSUSerNotification

Tags: nsview, nswindow, nsusernotification

Is there any way to display a custom view or window as a NSUserNotification in Mac OS X? I want to display additional information such as an image and as I understand I cannot do that with the standard NSUserNotification. Failing that, is there a way simply add a notification to the list and display my own pop over?

Thanks in advance, Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display a custom view or custom window as a NSUserNotification. A third party tool which could help is the [Growl SDK](http://growl.info/downloads). If you want to stick to use NSUserNotification, beginning in OS X 10.9 there is a new property *[contentImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSUserNotification/contentImage)* you could set to display a custom image in your notification, e.g. like this:

[image: custom image in NSUserNotification]

There seem to be also some new interaction possibilities for NSUserNotifications which aren't properly documented in the class reference, too, but which are also described in the Foundation Release Notes. You could check the new * responsePlaceholder* property, which I haven't tested yet.